# How to center align this element using css selector?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-selectors, antd

Trying to change ink bar into a circle, that I have done however, I am having a difficult time trying to center align it. Can anyone give me some advice?

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
  display: flex;
  //align-items: center;
  //vertical-align: middle;
  width: 8px !important;
  height: 8px;
  line-height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[image: Edit shy-firefly-phex9]

Comment: just add `.ant-tabs-ink-bar { left: 28px}`

Comment: @demkovych Thanks. I have tried this before however, that's a static alignment ideally I want it to be responsive. To always align in the middle no matter what size of the tab

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

With your provided CSS, try this

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
  left: 22.5px;
  width: 8px !important;
  height: 8px;
  line-height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pseudo element.

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.ant-tabs-ink-bar::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  line-height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--antd-wave-shadow-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a container and give following CSS to the container.

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```